# Convert array of integers to comma-separated string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

It's a simple question; I am a newbie in C#, how can I perform the following

- I want to convert an array of integers to a comma-separated string.

I have

```
int[] arr = new int[5] {1,2,3,4,5};
```

I want to convert it to one string

```
string => "1,2,3,4,5"
```

Answer (score 657, accepted):

```
var result = string.Join(",", arr);
```

This uses the following overload of `string.Join`:

```
public static string Join<T>(string separator, IEnumerable<T> values);
```

Comment: You do not need to pass the explicit generic argument in this case. It will be inferred.

Comment: Pre .NET 4

    string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(arr, i => i.ToString()))

Comment: Is there a simple way to do the reverse of this? Take the string and put it into an array?

Comment: @Kory: Using String.Split method, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 153):

.NET 4

```
string.Join(",", arr)
```

.NET earlier

```
string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(arr, x => x.ToString()))
```

Comment: just realized i couldn't use the .net 4 version and i didn't understood why i was having an error until i saw your answer , thanks.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5. I tried to concat the comma separated numbers with a string. I got an error saying "cannot convert string[] to char". So the earlier version worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 16):

```
int[] arr = new int[5] {1,2,3,4,5};
```

You can use Linq for it

```
String arrTostr = arr.Select(a => a.ToString()).Aggregate((i, j) => i + "," + j);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can have a pair of extension methods to make this task easier:

```
public static string ToDelimitedString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> lst, string separator = ", ")
{
    return lst.ToDelimitedString(p => p, separator);
}

public static string ToDelimitedString<S, T>(this IEnumerable<S> lst, Func<S, T> selector, 
                                             string separator = ", ")
{
    return string.Join(separator, lst.Select(selector));
}
```

So now just:

```
new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.ToDelimitedString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use LINQ `Aggregate` method to convert array of integers to a comma separated string

```cs
var intArray = new []{1,2,3,4};
string concatedString = intArray.Aggregate((a, b) =>Convert.ToString(a) + "," +Convert.ToString( b));
Response.Write(concatedString);
```

output will be

> 1,2,3,4

This is one of the solution you can use if you have not .net 4 installed.

Comment: It performs poorly due to the string concatenation, though

Comment: yes it will perform poorly but before .net 4.0  String.join only take string array as parameter.Thus in that case we also need to convert in string .we can use ToString it perform better but there is problem of null exception