# How to convert array of Integers into comma separated string

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string

This is my integer array with Ids

```
GoalIds{int[7]}
    [0]: 31935
    [1]: 31940
    [2]: 31976
    [3]: 31993
    [4]: 31994
    [5]: 31995
    [6]: 31990
```

I am getting the above array from this code

```
Array GoalIds = FilteredEmpGoals.Select(x => x.GoalId).Distinct().ToArray();
```

I am trying to convert it to comma separated string like

```
31935, 31940, 31976, 31993, 31994, 31995, 31990
```

To achieve this I tried

```
var result = string.Join(",", GoalIds);
```

but its's giving me `"System.Int32[]"` in result.

Please let me update where I make a mistake here.

Ref: I looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756565/c-sharp-convert-array-of-integers-to-comma-separated-string) and the example is working fine from there.

**UPDATE**

REF: As @paqogomez suggested

I was trying to store the values in a Array but may be it was not handling the values correctly. Now I did change the code for making the array as below

```
int[] GoalIds = FilteredEmpGoals.Select(x => x.GoalId).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Now it's working fine for me.

Comment: try GoalIds{int32[7]} ?

Comment: change `Array GoalIds` to `int[] GoalIds` or `var GoalIds`

Comment: And a tiny correction, use ", " instead of "," in the string.Join().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In declaring `GoalIds` as an `Array` type, you are not getting an iterator to be able to run in `String.Join`.

Try:

```
int[] GoalIds = FilteredEmpGoals.Select(x => x.GoalId).Distinct().ToArray();
var result = string.Join(",", GoalIds);
```

As @JeppeStigNielsen notes in the comments, this is also valid and eliminates the `ToArray` call:

```
var GoalIds = FilteredEmpGoals.Select(x => x.GoalId).Distinct();
```

Comment: You can also drop the `.ToArray()` call (use `var`). `string.Join` has (generic) overloads that take an `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, I mentioned that in the comments above, but perhaps it needs an edit to emphasize.

Answer (score 2):

I have run this code in c# and its work fine dont know what is your problem

```
int[] GoalIds = new int[7] { 31935,31940, 31976,31993, 31994, 31995, 31990};
var a = string.Join(",", GoalIds);
Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Please read my question again, I listed that from where I am getting the array. It's dynamically created and the length is also unknown

Comment: by the way it's working fine with the int [] GoalIds..., I was making it with Array.

Comment: @AmitJoki where is your answer?