# How do I assign string array values into single variable

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I have managed to get a list of names from a database, join the first and last name, put these names into an array so that they can be called up in say a MessageBox. How do I place the values from a dynamic string array into a string variable preferably separated by commas.

Here is my code so far:

```
        string[] array = new string[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            array[i] = Join(fullname);
        }


        foreach (string i in array)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(i);
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756565/c-sharp-convert-array-of-integers-to-comma-separated-string

Comment: Do you want to show each of them separately after you combined them? Because it seems that foreach loop does that.

Comment: Thanks you guys. I got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string.Join:

```
var myString = string.Join(",", array);
```